# How do I log into a "Flash Website" with WebClient and download a file using c# ?

Tags: c#, flash, authentication, webclient

I want to login in a website and download a .csv file and the file download button is located in second tab. But the website is required flash player.
Here's one of my attempts:

```
 public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
```

and

```
var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
        client.BaseAddress = @"https://example.com/";
        var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
        loginData.Add("username", "my user");
        loginData.Add("password", "my pwd");
        client.UploadValues("login/", "POST", loginData);

        string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("After login page");
```

Result:-

> ### EXAMPLE
>
> ### Welcome to example
>
> Example is a reporting tool that tracks your music sales. This is
>   where you can check how your releases are selling, update your account
>   information and see quarterly/monthly statements. Information is
>   updated in real time, so the numbers you are seeing are current.
>
> ### Why am I Seeing This Page?
>
> If you are seeing this page, you do not have Adobe Flash Player
>   (version 9, or higher) installed to your browser, and/or you do not
>   have javascript enabled. If you are still seeing this page after
>   installing Adobe Flash Player, and have javascript enabled, please
>   contact us at support@example.com
>
> Get Adobe's Flash Player
>
> © example, 2007

Comment: The flash application is very likely making calls to the server to present it's data (at the very least, you could make a direct call to download the file without interacting with the application). You could install a tool like fiddler to watch these requests, and make those requests programatically without having to load the flash application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this with simple WebClient.

To do what you need, I suggest you to use browser automation with Selenium and Chrome Driver. Since browser already handle flash, you just need to use Selenium to navigate and do what you want.

Comment: I used Selenium it didn't download the file. It did just login because login page is not flash but after login it did nothing

Comment: There is another way to do this without webclient? or tell me there is need to install any plugin in Selenium which is support flash

Comment: @GurpreetGill I really dont know. I had some trouble with flash, I was doing a web crawler, and the sites that I was crawling have captcha, so I used Death By Captcha to solve them, but there were one site that captcha was a flash component, and it made me change to selenium, I have no problem with downloading all the page.

Comment: Thanks, Alberto Monteiro I will try, after that I will tell you the result

Comment: @GurpreetGill You are welcome, if you need something else, let me know. I hope you can solve you problem :D

Comment: It did not download the file. Please tell me how to use Selenium in brief I am new user of it. I just installed add-ons in my Firefox browser there is need to install anything more?

Comment: There is a simple tutorial in youtube that you can see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ac4hKSfQ9s 

After that, you can see this video to see how to work with flash in selenium https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wd2NZLyvNAU, it uses java but is almost same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98437/discussion-between-gurpreet-gill-and-albertomonteiro).

Comment: It did not download the file
because I haven't element id,name etc any info. There is any way to click on that button by using coordinates of browser